# using variables in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have VS 2010.

I try using variable in SSRS.

Adding variable as explained on: http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/11/24/deciding-whether-to-use-an-expression-or-a-variable-in-ssrs.html

Several problems:

1. I am using above, and cannot see the "readonly" parameter.
2. I am trying doing something like (in expression): =Variables!MyVariable.Value, and I got an error while trying to compile the report: Error  1   : Value is invalid. InvalidIdentifier.
3. I need to set variable value as on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255208.aspx - Maybe this is for VS 2014. Is there any way doing that for VS 2012?

Thanks :)

Comment: For 3, see if this helps:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255208(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: That's exactly the same link I gave! I have seen that, but I have also mentioned I have Visual studio 2010, and I cannot see "readonly" parameter, and the code is not compiled.

Comment: Not exactly the same.   Your link was the page for SQL 2014.   Since you asked if it can be done for 2012, I gave the link to the same page for SQL 2012.

Comment: Nevertheless, again, I have the same problems: I cannot see "readonly" property, and still the syntax: =Variables!MyVariable.SetValue("123") return exception: setValue is invalid. Invalid identifier.